# Android development environment in virtual machine

Tags: android, virtual-machine, emulation

I have a question that looks quite complicated. I need to setup a complete development environment for Android in a virtual machine. I mean, create a virtual machine (player is Virtualbox last version) with Windows 8.1 as guest os.
In this vm, I installed Android Studio which works quite well. My problem is in running any android virtual device. I know I can't run x86 based emulator because I can't disable hyper-v, but I read somewhere that is should be possible to run arm based emulator (even if they are very slower). In fact, I can create and start an emulator, but it stuck with a blank screen, nothing happens and, of course, I can't deploy any application.
My question is:
1. Is it possible to run an AVD in a virtual machine?
2. My virtual machine has a memory of 2GB, maybe this isn't enough for running the AVD?

Thank you in advance

Comment: strange that you didn't get any responses, did you ever find a solution?